# Bytefield - Help with big datagram

Tags: bytefield

I've a datagram with approx. 80 bits. I don't want to divide it in bytes because most of the fields have a length different from 8 bits.

```
    \usepackage{bytefield}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=0.5em]{80}
    \bitheader[b]{0,4,10,20,21,38,46,47,64,71,72,80}\\
    \bitbox{8}{PayLoad} &
    \bitbox{1}{Tipo de Mensagem} &
    \bitbox{7}{C.Latitude 

        Un} & 
    \bitbox{17}{C.Latitude 

        Dec.} &
    \bitbox{1}{Coord.Latitude Car.} &
    \bitbox{8}{Coord.Longitude Un.} &
    \bitbox{17}{Coord.Longitude Dec.} &
    \bitbox{1}{Coord.Longitude Car.} &
    \bitbox{10}{Condutividade} &
    \bitbox{6}{Temperature
        unit} &
    \bitbox{4}{Temperature dec} \\
    \end{bytefield}

    \end{document}
```

And this is the output, a mess:

[image: frame example]

What I would like is that all the fields would have the same size or the size according to size of the name, not the size according to the number of bits. Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: Please complete code snippet to complete but small document. On the first sight probably you have problem with image width (seems to bi to wide). Welcome to TeX. SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example in pages 18-19 from [`bytefield`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/bytefield#page=19) documentation proposes to use `rotating` package and place labels above each field.

The result in this case looks:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield, rotating}

\newcommand{\bitlabel}[2]{%
\bitbox[]{#1}{%
\raisebox{0pt}[4ex][0pt]{%
\turnbox{45}{\fontsize{7}{7}\selectfont#2}%
}%
}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=0.5em]{80}
\bitlabel{8}{PayLoad} &
\bitlabel{1}{Tipo de Mensagem} &
\bitlabel{7}{C.Latitude Un} & 
\bitlabel{17}{C.Latitude Dec.} &
\bitlabel{1}{Coord.Latitude Car.} &
\bitlabel{8}{Coord.Longitude Un.} &
\bitlabel{17}{Coord.Longitude Dec.} &
\bitlabel{1}{Coord.Longitude Car.} &
\bitlabel{10}{Condutividade} &
\bitlabel{6}{Temperature unit} &
\bitlabel{4}{Temperature dec} \\
\bitheader[b]{0,4,10,20,21,38,46,47,64,71,72,80}\\
\bitbox{8}{} &
\bitbox{1}{} &
\bitbox{7}{} & 
\bitbox{17}{} &
\bitbox{1}{} &
\bitbox{8}{} &
\bitbox{17}{} &
\bitbox{1}{} &
\bitbox{10}{} &
\bitbox{6}{} &
\bitbox{4}{} \\
\end{bytefield}

\end{document}
```